# Java Integer to Binary Converter Code

Tags: java, binary, integer

I am trying to write a basic calculator. One of the things I want my calculator to have is a base arithmetic converter that gives an output when you input a base 10 integer.

I tried to write code for it on my own and it took nearly 3 hours just to figure out how to convert a number to a given base and it works good enough so far but I have one problem - when I try to convert an integer to base 2 (binary) my calculator does not work for numbers bigger than 1025.

I thought the problem was because there is a max value an integer can hold or something so I tried "BigInteger" but since it does not support remainder "%" operation I could not make it work.

```
else if(c.equals("Base")) {
    g = 0;
    l = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter the number (Integer) you want to convert");
    f = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the arithmetic base you want for your new number");
    m = scan.nextInt();
    for (;f>=1;) {
        h=f%m; 
        f=f/m;
        k = (int)Math.pow(10,g);
        g++;
        l =l + (h*k);
    }
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Sorry if the code is really bad and there are more efficent ways, i just wanted it to be mine instead of looking it up.

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the "binary representation" in an `int` variable, since that limits you to 10 digits. You can use a String instead.

Comment: Should i change them all or is it enough if i just change " int l " to "String l" ?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to [indent your code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44693520/edit) properly if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: Is it okay now ?

Comment: @Biazs You should certainly change `l` to `String`, and you can eliminate `k` and `g`.

Comment: `System.out.println(Integer.toString(f, m));`

Comment: @khelwood i dont see any reason to go hard on someone who just posted their first question ever too but thanks, i got my answer and will try to indent my code better for future questions.

Comment: @Biazs I wasn't going hard on you. I'm glad you're going to try and indent your code better. Good luck for future questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46002263/8491011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store the "binary representation" in an int variable, since that limits you to 10 digits.

Instead, you can use a `String` variable to hold the result:

```
String l = "";
while (f > 0) {
    h = f % m; 
    f = f / m;
    l = h + l;
}
System.out.println(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `BigInteger` class, you can use the mod method instead of "%".

```
BigInteger myBigInteger = new BigInteger("943838859");
System.out.println(myBigInteger.mod(BigInteger.TEN));
```

This will print 9.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I've tried myself (modulo/divide/add):

```
    int decimalOrBinary = 345;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    do {
        builder.append(decimalOrBinary % 2);
        decimalOrBinary = decimalOrBinary / 2;
    } while (decimalOrBinary > 0);

    System.out.println(builder.reverse().toString()); //prints 101011001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a 3 lines of code using a recursive funtion,

```
public static String convertToBase(int n, int b) {
    return n > 0 ? (convertToBase(n / b, b) + n % b) : "";
}
```